# override List<baseClass> with List<derivedClass>

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class

I have base classes like this:

```
public class Scene
{
    public IList<SceneModel> Models {get; set;}
}

public class SceneModel { }
```

and derived classes like this:

```
public class WorldScene : Scene
{
    public override IList<WorldModel> Models {get; set;}
}

public class WorldModel : SceneModel { }
```

So my question is, how do I manage this. As it stands the compiler isn't happy with this (and to be honest it looks a bit weird to me anyway). So is what I'm trying to do impossible? And if so, why? Or is it possible and I'm just going about it the wrong way?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use generics

```
public class BaseScene<T>
    where T : SceneModel
{
    public IList<T> Models {get; set;}
}

public class Scene : BaseScene<SceneModel>
{
}

public class WorldScene : BaseScene<WorldModel>
{    
}
```

Each type of scene will be parametrized by corresponding model type. Thus you will have strongly typed list of models for each scene.

Comment: Wow, I never knew how to do this. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is REALLY useful, this basically saved my project from having a lot of unnecessary reflection, or tons of code duplication. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamentally impossible.

What would happen if you write

```
Scene x = new WorldScene();
x.Models.Add(new OtherModel());
```

You just added an `OtherModel` to a `List<WorldModel>`.

Instead, you should make the base class generic.